# What happened to capacitor js storage library?

Tags: capacitor, ionic-storage

Plenty of results all over the internet linking to
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/storage

The page is gone and the package seems to be deprecated. I can't find any explanation for its disappearance. I also can't determine what's out there that replaces its functionality. I need to access the native storage API's in a capacitor app.

SOLVED:
When capacitor 4 came out they renamed the API from `@capacitor/storage` to `@capacitor/preferences`. This is documented very poorly. Updated link is here
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/preferences

Comment: It looks like the storage plugin was removed in Capacitor 4.0.  I can't see any announcement or explanation.  It's ... just ... gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED: When capacitor 4 came out they removed the @capacitor/storage API and replaced it with a more limited @capacitor/preferences. This change is documented very poorly. The updated link is here https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/preferences